# Move up by UP key from textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html form we need to move up or down using arrow keys to shift focus in the fields. following code works fine for all input elements. but in case of textarea there could be multiple lines so, if we move up or down cursor moves up or down in the textarea itself.

Now, I'm not getting how to move up the focus, if the cursor reaches in the first line of the textarea while pressing up arrow  OR move down the focus if the cursor reaches at the end or in the last line of the textarea while pressing down arrow key.
Here is my partial code:

```
var INPUT_SELECTOR = ':input:enabled:visible';
var inputs = $(INPUT_SELECTOR)

$("form").on("keypress", "input", function(event){
   // i is current input
  if(event.keyCode  === 38){ //action == 'up'
       inp = inputs[i > 0 ? parseInt(i) - 1 : inputs.length - 1];
  }

  if(event.keyCode  === 40){ //action == 'down'
      inp = inputs[i < inputs.length - 1 ? parseInt(i) + 1 : 0];
  }
 // focus on the input
   moveFocusTo(inp);
});
```

Our requirement for the up and down arrow keys is same as `tab` and `shift+tab` behaviour. everything is done, we have just stuck at textarea.

Comment: maybe you need to add the textare to the `on`: `$("form").on("keypress", "input, textarea", function(event) {`

Comment: @lolka_bolka: I wonder if input considers textarea also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget#1003983

```
event.relatedTarget
```

Then you can check to see during the event what element the user is focused on and act accordingly.